# read return 1 when reading from a socket even it read more

Tags: c, linux, sockets, netcat

When I read from a SOCK_STREAM socket like this:

```
int t;
while ((t = read(clientsocket, buff, 128) > 0))
{
  write(1, buff, t);
}
```

read always return 1, but if I look into buff with gdb I can see the whole line I sent.
I'm using netcat to send data to the server.

Comment: I'm quite an expirienced C programmer and yet I ran into the same problem -- just misplaced left paren two symbols left. Took me an hour to debug :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is incorrect due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

```
while ((t = read(clientsocket, buff, 128) > 0))
```

and results in `t` being assigned the result of `read(clientsocket, buff, 128) > 0`, which will be `0` or `1`.

To correct, change to:

```
while ((t = read(clientsocket, buff, 128)) > 0)
```